# Get Azure Cosmos Table values to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, azure, azure-cosmosdb

My goal is to change a text in my Html to a value from Azure Cosmos DB Table. How can I do that?

This is what I tried so far:

I'm using `Azure Cosmos DB` with the `Table API`. In this DB I have created a Table `MyTable`. In this Table I have one example entity:

```
Example Entity -> MyColumn: MyValue || MyColumn2: MyValue2 || ...

                  PartitionKey: 0 || RowKey: 0 || Text: MyText
```

I want `MyText` to be in an HTML. For this I created a WebApplication in VS2019 with this `.html`:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="MyJS.js" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MyJS.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="MyFunc()">whaddup</button>
    <p id="MyId">text</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And this `.js`:

```
function MyFunc() {

    var azure = require('azure-storage');

    var tableSvc = azure.createTableService('myAccountName', 'myPrimaryKey', 'myEndpoint');

    var query = new azure.TableQuery()
        .where('PartitionKey eq ?', '0');

    tableSvc.queryEntities('MyTable', query, null, function (error, result, response) {
        if (!error) {

            for (var key in result.entries) {
                var value = result.entries[key];
                for (var colName in value) {
                    var colVal = value[colName];
                    if (colName != ".metadata") {
                        var x = document.getElementById("MyId");
                        x.innerHTML = colVal._;
                        console.log(colName + ": " + colVal._);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The Html is just a button and a text. When clicking the button the text should change via the javascript.

**The first error** I encountered with this was `'require' is not defined` when clicking the button. To fix this I used [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

**Then the next problem** was that my function could not be found. I fixed this by changing `function MyFunc() {...}` to `window.MyFunc = function() {...}`.

**And I ran into the next problem**. When clicking the button I got this error:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at
```

`'https://myAccountName.table.cosmos.azure.com/MyTable?%24filter=PartitionKey...'`

```
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Well I tried to fix this. I've seen something about using a proxy so I changed:

```
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService('myAccountName', 'myPrimaryKey', 'myEndpoint');
```

to this:

```
var tableSvc = azure.createTableService('myAccountName', 'myPrimaryKey', 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/' + 'myEndpoint');
```

**And now I got to this error** when clicking the button:

```
GET 
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://myAccountName.table.cosmos.azure.com/MyTable?%24filter=PartitionKey... 
401 (Unauthorized)
```

**And now last but not least two error messages that might be important** to mention:

When going on this URL:

```
https://myAccountName.table.cosmos.azure.com/MyTable?%24filter=PartitionKey...
```

I get to see this:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"MediaTypeNotSupported","message":{"lang":"en-us","value":"None of the provided media types are supported\r\nActivityId: someActivityIdHere, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.4.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/6.2.9200.0\nRequestID:someRequestIDhere\n"}}}
```

When visiting this URL:

```
https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://myAccountName.table.cosmos.azure.com/MyTable?%24filter=PartitionKey...
```

I get to see this:

```
Missing required request header. Must specify one of: origin,x-requested-with
```

Comment: apart from your actual problem: Are you really sure you want to embed your Cosmos DB  primary key into the client-side javascript code? This is a BAD idea.

Comment: Guess I won't do it then. Thanks for the hint. Seems like I gotta find another way for my HTML :/

Comment: You probably want to build a backend API that you frontend website calls. Only this backend talks to the database

Comment: I will try to do that. Do you have a example that I could recreate maybe?

Comment: Sure. Like this https://github.com/ssemyan/TodoServerless A nice serverless example using Azure Functions. Instead of using C# for the Function, you could also write that in JS